# looking for commonality between lists

Tags: python, list

python newbie -

I have multiple text documents that contain users from several AD groups, I need to parse through each document and group users(usernames) by their group membership: for instance: 
Marketing doc has Marketing_grp:

```
John, Bob, Sally
```

Sales doc has Sales_grp:

```
Bob, Ron, Jeff
```

Technology doc has Technology_grp:

```
Bob, Mike, Sally
```

I need to be able to see that both Bob and Sally belong to multiple groups and I need to know what those groups are, how can I accomplish this with Python?

The data in the text file is in the form of email addresses as in username@company.com

```
#AD Group Usage
import re
from sys import argv
import shelve

script, filename = argv

def ADgrps(filename):
    f=open(filename, "r+")
    text=f.read()
    ad_grps = re.findall(r'[\w]+(?=@)', text)
    return ad_grps
```

Comment: how big are the text documents? can you read all 3 into memory ?

Comment: There will be about 50 documents some with 12 users, others with 100+ users

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this.

```
import re
import sys

groups = {}
for s in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(s) as f:
        for t in re.findall(r"[\w]+(?=@)", f.read()):
            if t in groups:
                groups[t].append(s)
            else:
                groups[t] = [s]

# Do stuff with the data.
```

Now you have a dictionary mapping emails to the files they appear in.  This code expects the names of the relevant files to be passed as command-line arguments.

Comment: Excellent! Really appreciate your help. Just out of curiosity, is it just experience that I need or is there a good book and/or course you can recommend for learning python?